# Adjust rows in SQL Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-express

We have a field where users sometimes input incorrect info. It wasn't a problem until now when we tried exporting the info to an external program: the data is causing problems. So the idea is now to fix the rows that have the incorrect data. The problem is that the issue is not in all fields, so I am not sure how to adjust it without accidentally deleting valid info.

I want to remove the space and the "J" and the input after it (it always starts with "J"). I did a query with `Left([EU-VAT NR], InStr([EU-VAT NR], "J") - 1)`, but the problem is that I still want the "SE" and "RO" rows that don't have the incorrect info.

```
RO 9999999 J11/1/1111
SE999999999
RO9999999
RO99999999 J11/11/1111 
RO 99999999
```

What I've thought of is exporting to Excel and then use text-to-columns to split the info up and delete unwanted info to then paste the corrected info back into the table, but since it is a lot of rows it is impossible to detect if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I see a problem, but I don't see a question here. Can you update your post with a question?

Answer (score 0):

Create and use small helper function in your query:

```vb
Public Function TrimSpaceJ(ByVal Value As String) As String

    TrimSpaceJ = Split(Value, " J")(0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is the only "J" in string, consider:

`Trim(IIf(InStr([EU-VAT NR],"J")>0,Left([EU-VAT NR],InStr([EU-VAT NR],"J")-1),[EU-VAT NR]))`

Or

`Trim(IIf([EU-VAT NR] LIKE "*J*",Left([EU-VAT NR],InStr([EU-VAT NR],"J")-1),[EU-VAT NR]))`